# Append new row before button which is calling the function

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am relatively new to Javascript. Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
   function insertAnswer(){
              //table       
              var innerTable = document.getElementById('inner_table');
              //the new row to be placed before this button         
              var buttonAddAnswer = document.getElementById ("addMoreAnswer");
          var row = document.createElement('tr');
          var col = document.createElement('td');
          var col2 = document.createElement('td');
          var newCount = counter + 1;
          col2.innerHTML = (counter + 1) + " <input type='text' name='answer" + newCount + "' id='answer" + newCount + "' class='mlselect' maxlength='200' size='90' > &nbsp <label>Go to:</label><input type='text' name='goTo' id='goTo' class='mlselect' maxlength='10' size='10' >"; 
          row.appendChild(col);
          row.appendChild(col2);
          innerTable.appendChild(row);
          //innerTable.parentNode.insertBefore(row, buttonAddAnswer);
          counter++;

        }
```

If I want to insert my row before the button, how do I go about it? I have tried `toinsertBefore`, but it does not seem to work. Can someone please steer me towards the right direction?

Comment: share your markup too.

Comment: If you know the index of the row that the button is in, you an use something like `tableSection.insertBefore(newRow, tableSection.rows[i])` where *tableSection* is a reference to the tbody, thead or tfoot that the button is in.